# Datagridview crashing Visual Studio 2013

Tags: datagridview, visual-studio-2013

I have run into a very strange problem. Whenever I try to drag and drop a datagridview on a fresh project or open a project that contains datagridview, the visual studio will crash. First it will say visual studio is checking for a solution and then visual studio is restarting. When I debug, I get this:
[image]

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing it, deleted the .suo files, signed in with different user, tried visual studio ultimate and community with update 4, opened VS in safemode. I have followed this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f2edce39-25fd-44d4-8bd2-614859ccfb62/datagridview-causing-visual-studio-to-crash?forum=visualstudiogeneral and done everything, so far did everything I could find in google...still nothing works. This only happend for datagridview. I am using windows 8.1. I also installed the OS again. VS seemed to work first for a few days, then it went back to giving the same trouble again. Can anyone help me with this issue, please?

[P.S. One of my friend is having the same problem, but for textbox.]